# Teams Copilot plugin search calls api per letter. Can we restrict to 3 letters before calling api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

If I type M, Mi, Mic, Micr, Micro ... in the copilot plugin search, our API gets hit nine times before the user types Microsoft.

Is there a way we can restrict the search API request to be hit after 3 letters?

Comment: Could you please confirm, are you using ME as backend side or any other?

Comment: @Pooran - could you please share screenshot of how you are invoking this?

Comment: We are using ME as backend @Sayali-MSFT

Wajeed https://m365x22354427-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/admin_m365x22354427_onmicrosoft_com/EQr_ht_dYRNJiEHAdgBfZBIB54Ot5r8y0PiZHKna0eAM8A?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0RpcmVjdCJ9fQ&e=F1cFlw

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information, we will check this internally and let you know the update.

Comment: Hello @Pooran - We have seen your video and looks like your ME is working in Teams but not working in Outlook client and your actually posted issue is something else. If you use ME and type something, it will call backend multiple times based on the speed you type. If you type just one character and wait, it will call API, so it is by design behaviour. Regarding your ME not working in Outlook, Kindly check if you have enabled Outlook channel or check if you are using correct version of Outlook to test it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ME and type something, it will call backend multiple times based on the speed you type.

If you type just one character and wait, it will call API, so it is by design behavior.

Regarding your ME not working in Outlook, Kindly check if you have enabled Outlook channel or check if you are using correct version of Outlook to test it.